# xml elements with same attribute names getting overriden

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mule-el, mule-esb

```
My XML Structure looks like below:-   
<element>
 <note nom="Rock" >Roll</note>
 <note nom="Bands" >
   <note nom="Unit" >jayz<note>
   <note nom="Unit" >eminem<note>
   <note nom="Unit" >drake<note>
 </note>
</element>
```

After transformation I am only able to retain the last unit value Drake. The first two unit values are overridden during transformation.

```
Need help with the dataweave transformation (XML to JAVA)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes currently the attributes are being lost, though you can map them by hand.

```
payload.notes.*note map ((note, index) -> {
    (note: note) if note != null,
    (note.@)
})
```

Taking this xml as input

```
<notes>
  <note nom="Rock" >Roll</note>
  <note nom="Bands"/>
  <note nom="Unit" >jayz</note>
  <note nom="Unit" >eminem</note>
  <note nom="Unit" >drake</note>
</notes>
```

Having said this there is going to be a new writer flag on next release to make json writer and java writer persist the attributes

Comment: I am expecting the output to be an arraylist like {Rock=Roll, Band ={Unit=Jayz,Unit=eminem,unit=drake}}

Comment: An array list? that looks more like a map